# Package Manager/Update Problem

Tags: software-center, package-management, virtualbox

I recently downloaded Virtualbox version 4.2.12, and I clicked the .deb file, which brought up the Ubuntu Software Center. I clicked upgrade as I had a previous version installed, and it did it successfully. Then when I rebooted Ubuntu, I got a serious error from Package Manager saying: "Unknown Error:'' (E:The package virtualbox-4.2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." Then it goes on to say: "This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies." Strangely, The Ubuntu Software Center didn't give a notification about unmet dependencies. Since then, Ubuntu Software Center and Package Manager can't Update, Install and Uninstall Software.

I also recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 the day that it came out, if that helps.

Comment: Did you purge previous versions of VirtualBox before you installed the upgraded packages?

Comment: No I didn't. I have been doing it this way to update VirtualBox. Update Manager and Ubuntu Software Center both crash when I open it with or without the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install new versions of Virtualbox a good way is to follow the [official installation page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads):

- In practice you have to add this line to /etc/apt/sources.list

  ```
  deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib
  ```

  (change "raring" with the name of your release)
- Then do this command to save the gpg key:

  ```
  wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
  ```
- and finally install it by doing this:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the dependencies are unmet *among the currently enabled repositories*.

Enable the Multiverse repository in the Software Sources:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Repositories_in_Ubuntu
Open the Ubuntu Software Center, open the "Edit" menu, hit "Software sources".